# Repeated objects in protobuffers - c

Tags: c, protocol-buffers

Im having difficulties with sending repeated objects with protobuffers in c.
I have declared object im trying to send like so

```
message IfconfigCfg {
    repeated string name        = 1; 
}
```

and i am trying to populate in C like this

```
        ifconfig_cfg.n_name = 2;
        ifconfig_cfg.name = (char*)malloc ( 4 );
        strcpy (ifconfig_cfg.name[0], "la\0");
        strcpy (ifconfig_cfg.name[1], "bc\0");
```

but im getting inconsistent results and i cant find any good reference about it for C implementation. Can anyone help me please.
It would be greatly appreciated.
Regards, Blaz
I

Comment: There is no official C implementation of protobuf, as far as I know. What library are you using?

Comment: What is this supposed to be? `repeated string name = 1;` Is this supposed to be pseudo code for having multiple pointers to strings?

Comment: @Gerhardh That's valid protobuf syntax, not supposed to be C.

Comment: im using this implementation: 
https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c and version 3 of protocol-buffers

Answer (score 1):

There is an [example in the documentation](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c/wiki/Examples#strings) that does almost exactly what you're after:

```
message DMessage {
  repeated string d=1;
}
```

```
  DMessage msg = DMESSAGE__INIT;  // DMessage (repeated string)
  void *buf;                      // Buffer to store serialized data
  unsigned len,i,j;               // Length of serialized data

  msg.n_d = argc - 1;                      // Save number of repeated strings
  msg.d = malloc (sizeof (char*) * msg.n_d);   // Allocate memory to store strings
  for (j = 0; j < msg.n_d; j++) {
      msg.d[j] = (char*)argv[j+1];         // Access msg.c[] as array
  }
  len = dmessage__get_packed_size (&msg);  // This is calculated packing length
  buf = malloc (len);                      // Allocate required serialized buffer length
  dmessage__pack (&msg, buf);              // Pack the data
```

Adapted to your case:

```
        ifconfig_cfg.n_name = 2;
        ifconfig_cfg.name = malloc(sizeof(char*) * ifconfig_cfg.n_name);
        ifconfig_cfg.name[0] = "la";
        ifconfig_cfg.name[1] = "bc";
```

I suggest you read up on how strings and pointers work in C, because your original code was trying to copy strings into unallocated memory and had needless extra null terminators.